# Parse LiveQuery Not Subscribing - Android (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, parse-platform

I am in the middle of rewriting my Android app from Java to Kotlin. I'm using [Parse LiveQuery on Android](https://github.com/parse-community/ParseLiveQuery-Android) and can't seem to get subscriptions working whatsoever.

I am using this code to start the LiveQuery but not getting any response. I know that the table in the DB has liveQuery enabled. I also know that the same subscription worked in the Java version of this app.

```
fun startListeningToNotifications() {
        //Build Live Query Client
        val parseLiveQueryClient = ParseLiveQueryClient.Factory.getClient()

        //Build Query
        var parseQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery<ParseObject>("Notifications")
        parseQuery.whereEqualTo("toUser", ParseUser.getCurrentUser())
        parseQuery.orderByAscending("createdAt")
        parseQuery.findInBackground { objects, e ->
            //Do something with notifications
        }

        //Build Live Query Listener
        var subscriptionHandling: SubscriptionHandling<ParseObject> = parseLiveQueryClient.subscribe(parseQuery)
        subscriptionHandling.handleSubscribe {
            Toast.makeText(this, "SUBSCRIBED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        subscriptionHandling.handleEvents { query, event, `object` ->
            fetchNotificationCount()
        }
        subscriptionHandling.handleError { query, exception ->
            Toast.makeText(this, exception.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
```

Any help is extremely appreciated. Been stuck on this for days now and the GitHub issue tracker is no help whatsoever as it's either all old, doesn't work with Kotlin or just a different issue all together.

**EDIT**

Attaching image of debugger here in the hopes it helps someone realise where I'm going wrong.
[image: Android Studio Debugger Snapshot]

Comment: Can you post java equivalent of this code

Comment: No. I am not able to do so. Apologies.

Comment: @BrandonStillitano then how to be sure it works with Java?

Comment: @YuriPopiv because the sample project in the repo i've linked to is working as expected.

Comment: What do you mean with `not getting any response`? Does `subscribe` method not return any value? Or does none your `findInBackground`, `handleSubscribe` and `handleEvents` callbacks is called?

Comment: @Ircover the ParseQuery finds the objects just fine.  It is the handleSubscribe and handleEvents that are doing nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. When specifying the server URL, if you use an nginx server, the port must be specified otherwise it will fail.

My parse config looked like this:

```
Parse.initialize(
                Parse.Configuration.Builder(context)
                        .applicationId("appId")
                        .clientKey("clientKey")
                        .server("https://yourdomain.com/database/parse")
                        .enableLocalDataStore()
                        .build()
        )
```

The correct configuration is:

```
Parse.initialize(
                Parse.Configuration.Builder(context)
                        .applicationId("appId")
                        .clientKey("clientKey")
                        .server("https://yourdomain.com:1337/parse")
                        .enableLocalDataStore()
                        .build()
        )
```